# Date between query in mysql not generated correct output

Tags: mysql

I stored date field as Varchar. 
When I use this query :

```
SELECT date
FROM g_m_tit
WHERE date BETWEEN '01.10.2015' AND '31.10.2015';
```

it generates the wrong output, as [shown below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrcB3.png)

[image]

Comment: in my opinion, I think this is because you are storing your dates in the wrong format.  You should be using something like `INSERT INTO g_m_tit ('date') VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01/31/2015', '%m/%d/%Y'));`  And your result from a select would look like `2015-01-31`

Comment: already dates were stored as 'varchar' form. I have to take data between two dates which stored as shown in image. I think there are some convertions are avilable for this date selection from varchar format. But I don't get the exact idea of the same..

Comment: In order to use `between` correctly ... You're going to have to convert the table to that format.  I'd just use a quick PHP script to `SELECT *` -- iterate through them .. convert the date to the correct MySQL format, and `INSERT` into a new (blank) table.  IMHO that's the 'correct' approach here.

Answer (score 1):

In your image note how the first 2 characters are between '01' and '31'. The between operator works on varchars using varchar "rules" e.g. '19' IS between '01' and '31' and that is why you are getting unwanted results. You are expecting date rules to be applied but your expectation isn't accurate.

Do not store dates as a string; but if you simply had to do it for some reason only a sequence such as YYYYMMDD allows you to reliably use between.

If you persist in storing the column as varchar with the pattern dd.mm.yyyy then try these:

```
SELECT
      `date`
FROM g_m_tit
WHERE str_to_date(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-31';

SELECT
      `date`
FROM g_m_tit
WHERE str_to_date(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') >= '2015-10-01') 
AND str_to_date(`date`,'%d.%m.%Y') < '2015-11-01';
```

both of these, as you can see, force you into changing the data, and you would need to do that every time you reference that "date" column - that is very inefficient.

Also, date is a reserved word, please avoid using such words as column names.

A final note: I prefer the second query above as I never use between for date ranges.

Comment: Why not use between?

Comment: Because between is "inclusive" of both the low and high values. To get a date/time range absolutely precise - regardless of the data type's level of precision - it is better that the high value is excluded.  It is hard to explain fully and be brief. Some might make an exception if only dealing with dates (no time of day) and use between, but I do not recommend using between for date ranges at all (e.g. in case the data precision could be altered). Best practice for date ranges is a combination of >= with < like my second example.

Answer (score 1):

With VARCHAR column, comparing to strings, that will be a character by character comparison, from left to right.

If you want string comparisons to be used for "date" comparisons, the date values will need to be stored in a *consistent* and *canonical* format, with the year first, then the month, then the day.  e.g. '2016.01.13'.

MySQL provides datatypes other than VARCHAR specifically for storing date and time values... `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`.

---

Dealing with date values stored in VARCHAR columns, in the format you have, is going to be some messy SQL. And MySQL is going to have to scan all rows to evaluate the expression; it won't be able to use a range scan operation.

One way to do it is to convert the strings into DATE values, and compare the DATE values.

```
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`      ,'DD.MM.YYYY')
 BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.10.2015','DD.MM.YYYY')
     AND STR_TO_DATE('31.10.2015','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

If there are any string values in `date` that can't be converted to a DATE, because the format doesn't match the specification, or an "invalid" date value, e.g. `32.13.2015`, the STR_TO_DATE function will return a NULL or throw an error (depending the SQL_MODE setting).

Answer (score 0):

create new column with "date" or "bigint" type

Update all rows inserting value from old  column to new (based on new column type)

Delete old column

Rename new one to "g_m_tit"

do not use varchar for dates! It causing probelms as u can see and its slower than date/bigint

To store date in:

"varchar(10)" u need 11 bytes + charset collate every query

"bigint" u need 8 bytes (available range condition)

"date" u need 3 bytes (available range, by part of date conditions and much more  )